# Why does std::chrono::time_point doesn't like arithmetics?

Tags: c++, c++11, arithmetic-expressions, c++-chrono

I was simply trying to measure the time passed between to time points:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main(){
//    std::chrono::time_point start1;  // <-- doesn't work
//    std::chrono::time_point end1;    // <-- doesn't work
    auto start1;                       // <-- does work
    auto end1;                         // <-- does work

    start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"Hello, World!"<<std::endl;
    end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end1 - start1).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

...and I noticed that `start1` and `end1` have to be defined with the `auto` type. If I explicitly define them with the type `std::chrono::time_point` the expression `end1 - start1` gives me "*binary operator '-' can not be applied to...*".

Why can I use arithmetic operators on `start1` and `end1` if they are defined with `auto`? Does `auto` automatically cast them into something that is compatible with arithmetic operators? I thought `auto` should just be the shorthand for the compiler to look what `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` returns type is?!

Comment: [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) is a class template.

Comment: If you use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` it works [fine.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3161124e7abf8f26)

Comment: @jaggedSpire Oh god! Thank you...must have overseen this...

Comment: `auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` should work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that `start1` and `end1` have to be defined with the `auto` type.

They don't *HAVE* to be, but it is useful, especially with complex templated types.

However, you can't declare an `auto` variable without initializing it in the same statement, otherwise it has nothing to deduce a data type from. It can't deduce a type from another statement, like you attempted to do.

Try this instead:

```
auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
...
auto end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

> If I explicitly define them with the type `std::chrono::time_point` the expression `end1 - start1` gives me "binary operator '-' can not be applied to...".

[`std::chrono::time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) is a templated type:

```
template< 
  class Clock, 
  class Duration = typename Clock::duration 
class time_point;
```

You are not providing any values for its template parameters.

[`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now) returns a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`.  If you don't use `auto`, you have to specify that complete type in your variable declarations:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
...
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Or, if you want to separate the declarations from the assignments:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start1;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end1;

start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
...
end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

You can simplify those a little with `using` aliases:

```
using hi_res_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using hi_res_time_point = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>;
```

```
hi_res_time_point start1 = hi_res_clock::now();
...
hi_res_time_point end1 = hi_res_clock::now();
```

```
hi_res_time_point start1;
hi_res_time_point end1;

start1 = hi_res_clock::now();
...
end1 = hi_res_clock::now();
```

> Why can I use arithmetic operators on `start1` and `end1` if they are defined with `auto`?

Because their types will be fully known to the compiler, and it will be able to resolve the appropriate [`operator-`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2) that operates on `time_point` values.

> Does `auto` automatically cast them into something that is compatible with arithmetic operators?

`auto` is just a shorthand that allows the compiler to auto-deduce a variable's data type based on what is being assigned to that variable at compile-time.

> I thought `auto` should just be the shorthand for the compiler to look what `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` returns type is?!

That is exactly what it does.  You were just not using `auto` correctly.